# getting Monday , june 5 , 2016 instead of June 5 ,2016 using DateTimeField

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an app using Django an my my model has the following field:

```
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
```

Using that I get  this:  June 5, 2016, 9:16 p.m.

but I need something like : Monday, June 5, 2016

How I can get that??

Any help will be great
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain where you get the datetime more detail. You get in django-admin or front-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context. In a template you can use the [date template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

```
<span>{{ my_date|date:"l, F j, Y" }}
```

or in Python context [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
my_date.strftime("%A, %B %W, %Y")
```

In case you just need the date (without time) you could consider using django's `models.DateField` instead of `models.DateTimeField`